# using sqlite data for dispalying the line on the map

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite, mkmapview

I want to retrieve the longitudes and latitudes from sqlite data, and then add this data into the array and use this array data as fake_location for displaying the location  of the user.

For solving this problem I am sending all my class TLocationManager.m file code
-(id)init{
        pointsArray = [[result componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] retain];
        NSLog(@"This is the good think to have %@",pointsArray);
        pointsArrayIndex = 0;
        //NSLog(@"%@",pointsArrayIndex);
        oldLocationsIndex = 0;

```
    [result release];

    oldLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first warning

```
[locations addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@,%@",dLongitude,dLatitude]];//over here i am getting warring  passing argument 1 of 'stringWithFormat:'from incompatible pointer type
```

replace it with

```
[locations addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",dLongitude,dLatitude]];//over here i am getting warring  passing argument 1 of 'stringWithFormat:'from incompatible pointer type
```

Second, Where did you get componentsByJoiningString function for NSMutableArray.

```
 //Over here getting warring 'NSMutableArray' may not respond to'-componentsByJoiningString'    
 result = [locations componentsByJoiningString:@" "]; // same as `fake_location`function
```

replace it with

```
result = [locations componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

See NSArray [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)..

Comment: This is the good think to have (null)
it show in console my array is still getting null value

Comment: I want to display the sqlite data which like this 42.336845,-71.126239
42.336953,-71.12639
42.337103,-71.12654
42.337275,-71.126711
42.337457,-71.126883
42.337629,-71.127076
42.3378,-71.127269
42.337908,-71.127419
42.338026,-71.12757
42.338079,-71.127656
in the result string

Comment: you mean like this"result = [locations componentsJoinedByString:@(" ")];"

Comment: see my edit..If you want to interpose coma(,) put ','. If you want to interpose space put space (" ") there

Comment: is still showing me null value .I think it problem the in sqlite data getting that's way it getting null value .It not executed the sqlite   select statement

Comment: well..then clear that bug first..

Comment: Thanks for helping me But Now i am going to delete this question i am not getting answer